# mktemp: failed to create directory via template Permission denied

Tags: permissions, software-installation, tmp

At first I wanted to install a package on a server to which I don't have root access. Since I don't have root access I tried to build it myself but I get an error in the configuration stage.

**Here is the commands I run:**

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/stella-emu/stella.git
cd stella/
./configure --prefix=$HOME/atari
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Running Stella configure...
mkdir: cannot create directory `/tmp/cg-2059': Permission denied
config.guess: cannot create a temporary directory in /tmp
Looking for C++ compiler... none found!
```

Is there any way I can fix this?

**Here are some diagnosis information**

```
-bash-4.2$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Dec  9 20:39 /tmp
-bash-4.2$ find /tmp -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf x | wc -c
12
-bash-4.2$ mkdir ~/tmp
-bash-4.2$ ls
amin  bs94  Maildir  public_html  skel.tar.gz  speedtest_cli.py  speedtest.py  stella  tajdari  tmp
-bash-4.2$ cd stella/
-bash-4.2$ TMPDIR="$HOME/tmp" ./configure --prefix=$HOME/atari
Running Stella configure...
Looking for C++ compiler... none found!
-bash-4.2$ type -a c++ g++ clang++
c++ is /usr/bin/c++
g++ is /usr/bin/g++
-bash: type: clang++: not found
-bash-4.2$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.11 (wheezy)
Release:    7.11
Codename:   wheezy
```

So now I'm trying to use [junest](https://github.com/fsquillace/junest) but again after running:

```
git clone git://github.com/fsquillace/junest ~/.local/share/junest
export PATH=~/.local/share/junest/bin:$PATH
```

I get:

```
-bash-4.2$ junest
mktemp: failed to create directory via template `/tmp/junest.XXXXXXXXXX': Permission denied
Error: null argument 
-bash-4.2$ junest -u
mktemp: failed to create directory via template `/tmp/junest.XXXXXXXXXX': Permission denied
Error: null argument
```

Comment: What ary your permissions on `/tmp`? Check with `ls -ld /tmp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [roaima’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409961/86440) for the `mktemp` issue.

Even with that fixed though, you won’t be able to build the current release of Stella. Stella needs GCC 4.8 or later to build, but Debian 7 only has GCC 4.7. You’ll need an older release of Stella (such as [3.7.2](https://github.com/stella-emu/stella/releases/tag/release-3.7.2) which is the version [in Debian 7](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/stella); I think [4.2](https://github.com/stella-emu/stella/releases/tag/release-4.2) should be OK too).

(I’m the Debian Stella maintainer.)

Comment: Can you provide the download link for the appropriate version please!?

Comment: I’ve added links in my answer.

Comment: Looking for sdl-config... none found!

Comment: `apt install libsdl1.2-dev` (look at `debian/control` for the list of build dependencies).

Comment: apt does not exist on the system.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, you can’t install stuff. Well you’ll have to build SDL then, or find another system to install Stella on...

Comment: how can i recognize sdl to stella after I build it in my home directory?

Comment: If you run `./configure --help` you should be able to find the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You need to arrange for the system administrator to fix the broken permissions on `/tmp`.

> ```
> ls -ld /tmp
> drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Dec 9 20:39 /tmp
> ```

Fix with:

```
chmod a=rwx,u+t /tmp
```

And check to make sure it's correct:

```
ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 7 root root 8192 Nov  1 14:19 /tmp
```

Then you can [address the rest of the build process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409959/100397).

Comment: Note that the `TMPDIR` fix in the question is good enough to get past the `mktemp` problem.

Comment: @StephenKitt yes, but how much else is going to break on this system with a badly configured `/tmp`?

Comment: Oh yes, I definitely agree the `/tmp` issue needs fixing. My comment was mostly in reaction to your last sentence (but *that’s* mostly there to link to my answer, I take it!).

Comment: The system is for my university and it's been running like this for ages now. Actually maybe it's on purpose so that students can do almost nth on the server!(they gave us this only to build ourselves a homepage on it. And i'm trying to more than what I'm supposed to! Actually if I ask them about the issue they might realize we can still do somethings and make the system more restricted!)

Comment: @aran no. The system has not been designed to run with such broken permissions on `/tmp`.

Comment: @roaima so you are saying that is the default!?:-/

Comment: @aran the correct settings are as I have described them. Yours is broken.

Comment: @roaima how do you know it's not broken by purpose in order to make it more difficult for us to install applications.

Comment: @aran, `/tmp` is used by _many_ other things than application installs.